# Have anyone tried Microsoft Graph API to read One drive image EXIF Data like location

Tags: onedrive, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to read a exif data of an Image particularly Location from One Drive using Microsoft graph api. Did any one tried to read location (longitude and latitude)?

Comment: Do you have any reference documents?

Answer (score 0):

I checked some documents and learned that this feature seems to be disabled in 2019, but I learned from here that there is a third-party tool that can achieve this function [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/how-to-auto-read-meta-data-from-images/m-p/355224).